# pandas ffill/bfill for specific amount of observation

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
 id     indicator 
 1          NaN
 1          NaN
 1          1
 1          NaN
 1          NaN
 1          NaN
```

In reality, I have several more ids. My question now is, how do I do a forward or backward fill for a specific range, e.g. for only the next/last 2 observations. My dataframe should look like this:

```
 id     indicator 
 1          NaN
 1          NaN 
 1          1
 1          1
 1          1
 1          NaN
```

I know the command

```
df.groupby("id")["indicator"].fillna(value=None, method="ffill")
```

However, this fills all the missing values instead of just the next two observations. Anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

almost there,
straight from the doc

> If method is specified, this is the maximum number of consecutive NaN values to forward/backward fill. In other words, if there is a gap with more than this number of consecutive NaNs, it will only be partially filled. If method is not specified, this is the maximum number of entries along the entire axis where NaNs will be filled. Must be greater than 0 if not None.

```
df.groupby("id")["indicator"].fillna(value=None,method="ffill",limit=3)
```

Comment: Although not specified by the OP, this method would likely have the unintended consequence of filling values from one `id` to the next.  The OP likely intended to only fill values within the same `id`.

Answer (score 7):

I think [`DataFrameGroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) or [`DataFrameGroupBy.bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html) with `limit` parameter is nicer:

```
df.groupby("id")["indicator"].ffill(limit=3)

df.groupby("id")["indicator"].bfill(limit=3)
```

Sample:

```
#5 value is in the end of group, so only one value is filled 
df['filled'] = df.groupby("id")["indicator"].ffill(limit=2)
print (df)
    id  indicator  filled
0    1        NaN     NaN
1    1        NaN     NaN
2    1        1.0     1.0
3    1        NaN     1.0
4    1        NaN     1.0
5    1        NaN     NaN
6    1        NaN     NaN
7    1        NaN     NaN
8    1        4.0     4.0
9    1        NaN     4.0
10   1        NaN     4.0
11   1        NaN     NaN
12   1        NaN     NaN
13   2        NaN     NaN
14   2        NaN     NaN
15   2        1.0     1.0
16   2        NaN     1.0
17   2        NaN     1.0
18   2        NaN     NaN
19   2        5.0     5.0
20   2        NaN     5.0
21   3        3.0     3.0
22   3        NaN     3.0
23   3        NaN     3.0
24   3        NaN     NaN
25   3        NaN     NaN
```